# Numpy giving wrong results computing transitive closure matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, graph-theory

This is the code I have been trying to run
I am pretty sure I have understood the algorithm wrong, but it is trying to calculate the transitive closure of the given matrix
But I am a beginner at this so I do not know the details.

```py
import numpy as np

def checkReach(mat):
    ''' Creates the reachablity table to check whether the given route is possible in the case of a directional graph/matrix'''
    order = len(mat)
    sum = np.empty([order, order], int)
    prev = np.identity(order, int)
    for i in range(order):
        prev = np.dot(prev, mat)
        prev[prev > 1] = 1
        prev[prev < 1] = 0
        sum = np.array(sum)+ np.array(prev)
    
    sum[sum > 1] = 1
    sum[sum < 1] = 0
    return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    adj_mat = [
    #   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]   Headings
        [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],  # 0th row
        [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  # 1st row
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  # 2nd row
        [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],  # 3rd row
        [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],  # 4th row
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  # 5th row
        [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],  # 6th row
        [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0],  # 7th row
        [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],  # 8th row
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]   # 9th row
    ]
    sum = checkReach(adj_mat)
    print(sum)
```

Expecting a matrix where the 2nd row is empty as it cannot go to any other vertices, but it gives different results every time... I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Projects\Algorith Checks\tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.247 seconds

[Running] python -u "c:\Projects\Algorith Checks\tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.252 seconds

[Running] python -u "c:\Projects\Algorith Checks\tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```